# java.io.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: java, jsp, jasper-reports, filenotfoundexception

Here is my Java code generating *JasperReports*'s report and open it in PDF format within the browser.

I am getting `java.io.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot find the path specified` error at this line:

```
String jrxmlFile = session.getServletContext().getRealPath(request.getContextPath()) + "D:/Reports/EmpDetails.jrxml";
```

Answer (score 1):

The system cannot find the path `yourcontextpathD:/Reports/EmpDetails.jrxml`.

You are mixing up the location on your hard drive and the servlet path settings.

The path to the report has to be relative to `yourcontextpath`, e.g. in an subfolder in the web context:

```
String jrxmlFile = session.getServletContext().getRealPath(request.getContextPath()) + "/reporting/EmpDetails.jrxml";
```

Answer (score 0):

`getRealPath` delivers the file system path starting at the directory of the web application. Passed is path with forward slashes `/`.

One suggestion would be to generate all reports in "WEB-INF/Reports/" or such.